# How to select one column in a dataframe and add this to an empty dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of 8 dataframes named `all_df`, this is only a part of the list.

```
    [      CloneID  P1Sig  P1STB  P1Cov  ...  P2Cov  P2Sig*S1/S2         r   r>=1

     0      849492   1268    167     88  ...     88  1300.556505 -0.025675  False

     1      847936    707     92    120  ...    120   926.126468 -0.309938  False

     2      848434    608     78     94  ...     94   654.800354 -0.076974  False

     3      849038   4374    507    110  ...    110  3860.066177  0.133141   True

     4      845994    796    103     71  ...     71   756.095437  0.052777   True

     ...       ...    ...    ...    ...  ...    ...          ...       ...    ...

     9591   833817   1444    164     94  ...     94  1428.984199  0.010508   True

     9592   834712    664     83    105  ...    105   640.329628  0.036966   True

     9593   760753   1512    168    127  ...    127  1416.322313  0.067554   True

     9594   834148    403     53    100  ...    100   472.107438 -0.171482  False

     9595   833601    574     72     72  ...     72   537.225705  0.068452   True


     [9596 rows x 10 columns]
```

For each dataframe in the list, column `r` should be extracted and added into a new dataframe called `df_relative` expression with the `CloneID` as index.

I only seem to get the last object in the list added to the new dataframe with

```
r_column= df_relatieve_expression[["r"]]
df_relatieve_expression[file]= r_column
```

The column name should be the name of the file of which this r value is computed from.

All filenames are in a tuple `all_files = ("day1.txt","day2.txt", "day4.txt", "day7.txt", "day14.txt", "day21.txt","day45.txt", "day90.txt")`

Comment: You have list of dataframes? `all_df=[df1, df2, df3, ..., dfn]` where `df` are `dataframes`? Then simply iterate through the list add `r` column to new empty `df`

Comment: how do you add r colum to the new df, there is where i get stuck. I only manage to get r column of the last dataframe  into the new dataframe

Comment: Is the CloneID same for all the dataframes?

Comment: Yes, all the CloneID are the same

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code here, but if I don't get you wrong then you probably might use this code below in order to achieve what you was expecting for:

```
col_R = all_df[['r']]
df_relative_expression['Colum name'] = col_R
```

Comment: That way i only add the r column of the last dataframe in de list into the new dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `all_df` with `enumerate` so it will give you **index** and **df** where **index** will help to get name of file from `all_files` tuple and **df** will hold the **df** from `all_df`

```py
df_relative = pd.DataFrame()
all_files = ("day1.txt", "day2.txt", "day4.txt", "day7.txt", "day14.txt", "day21.txt", "day45.txt", "day90.txt")
for idx, df in enumerate(all_df):
    df_relative[all_files[idx]] = df["r"]

# as mentioned in comments 'CloneId' is same across all df
df_relative.set_index(all_df[0]["CloneId"]) # setting 'CloneId' as index for new dataframe
```